# parsing String in Android

Tags: java, android, string, google-app-engine

I have this string that is pulled from a "ContactInfo" entity on the app engine datastore and in the string it contains all the children of each type. Anyone have any good ideas on how to parse this or organize it in some orderly fashion. I need it to show the first name, last name, address, etc all together for each entry and have a separate one for each person.

This is what the string logs as:

```
08-30 17:22:03.802: W/apples(18160): {"items":[{"description":"payment confirmed","emailAddress":"abc@aqw.com","id":"Fri Aug 30 17:20:35 EDT 2013","nameFirst":"Bill","nameLast":"Sanders","phone":"5555555555","state":"KS","streetAddress":"123 Rick Dr","zipCode":"44444","kind":"contactinfoendpoint#resourcesItem"},{"description":"payment confirmed","emailAddress":"qwe@msn.com","id":"Fri Aug 30 17:21:37 EDT 2013","nameFirst":"Frank","nameLast":"Lloyd","phone":"5554567896","state":"KY","streetAddress":"999 Rock St","zipCode":"44555","kind":"contactinfoendpoint#resourcesItem"}],"kind":"contactinfoendpoint#resources","etag":"\"NiDXI3T89oRrAPGJAhgGQje1Z0w/z0W4p01mjHc5cNgcOt3Kb_1xo8E\""}
```

Comment: This is valid JSON. Use a json parser.

Comment: What Sotirios says, and voting to close. Pick [org.json](http://www.json.org/javadoc/), [gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) or my favourite, [jackson](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks, I'll look into that. What kind of adapter would I need to make each entry show up in a listView or something of the sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you posted is a JSON object.

So, you could use [JSONObject class](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) to parse it, converting it to an object, and access its data in a more comfortable way.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(myString);
```

Also check for GSON, or Jackson, which are third-party JSON parsers

Comment: I'm assuming there is some sort of JSONObject to listView adapter out there?

Comment: Maybe.. But the relevant thing is that, even if there's no ListView adapter, this will still make it easy for you to work with the strings without parsing them manually.

Answer (score 2):

This is a valid JSON object. You can extract the desired fields with the built in JSON parser like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourString);
JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("items");
for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
    String firstName = items.getJSONObject(i).getString("nameFirst");
    String lastName = items.getJSONObject(i).getString("nameLast");
}
```

To display this in a list, you need to develop your own adapter. It can, for example, take the `items` array and use that for producing the cells. But there is no general solution for visualizing JSON data. (Other than plain text.)